# Best way to store wordings in my web application?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

Hi i want to store wordings used in my application where i could easily get them and use/reuse them.

Some example of wordings like loading messages or validation messages, or any information messages.

I have tried using .resx files to store some of these but one thing i hate about is i need to get that wording on the server which i get lazy after doing it so many times.

I also tried storing them in a javascript array but i realized that any user might be able to see all those wordings since it is stored on the client side. But i dont have anything to hide there. It is just i feel that it is not the right thing to do maybe?

Anybody has any good suggestions?

Comment: I mean, if the messages are not hiding some type of secure data then using javascript is completely appropriate to store these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store just some messages javascript is absolutely fine.

I may suggest you the following approach:

Create a js file as follows and name it `messages.js`

```
var messages = {
       "loading" : "Still loading",
       "validation1" : "Please fill the required field",
       "success" : "thats a success",
       "failure" : "some error",
       "custom1" : "custommsg1",
       "custom2" : "custommsg2"
}
```

Include it in your web page and use whichever custom message you want to use
like for example
when you want to use success use `message.success` and similarily `message.loading` and so on for other messages.

Make sure that the left hand side values are unique since these are key value pairs.

Comment: I like this answer. yes i dont have any security data that i need to hide. I just felt that doing this on javascript is a bad idea but upon seeing this answer i feel this is the right thing to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong that the user can see your wordings, and there is no way to hide data from user in web app. If you need to store secure data, keep them on the server, otherwise user can get from researching your app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a JSON file called messages.json

and create a service to read from that by doing a HTTP request

```
$http.get("messages.json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.messages = response.data;
 });
```

Now scope has a property which is globally accessible